# How to feed the video source based on time range?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

Standard HTML5 `video` element seems to work using [byte ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests). The problem is that the server I'm using to serve the video content doesn't support byte ranges. It only supports time ranges (as it's based on ffmpeg).

E.g. I can make a query(in seconds) such `http://example.com/myvideo.mkv?range=3.40-49` and it returns  video content from 3rd second point 40 ms to 49th second.

Question: is it possible to feed the media source buffer using time ranges? How do I know what time ranges does the media buffer needs and when(e.g. if the client seeks using the progress bar)?

I've checked several players such [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki) but they all assume the server supports byte range so I can't use them.

What I've tried so far:
I was thinking to use timestampOffset to feed the array buffer with the correct bytes(time range based) but I don't know when the client seeks and at what position(in seconds). Additionally I think I should fill the range missed but timestampOffset provides only an offset/start point. How do I know the range so that I can avoid overwriting possible already cached/buffered content?

I feel there are a lot of edge cases so I'm wondering if there is already a such player supporting time range instead of byte range. I basically just want to provide a `function (videoSourceBuffer, startTime, stopTime)` which fills `videoSourceBuffer` with the video content starting at `startTime` and stoping at `stopTime`.

```
  var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function() {
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
            sourceBuffer.timestampOffset = 0;
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(videoBinary);
    });
```

Comment: use fragmented mp4/dash. Its already split into many files (no need for byte ranges), and can bee fed directly into MSE.